# How to generate a video thumbnail in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda

How can I generate a video thumbnail in asp.net core?

I have used corecompat.system.drawing package for generating the thumbnail of images but I didn't find any package for generating the video thumbnail. Could you please help me for the same.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no free library for .NET standard that could generate a video thumbnail. There is some solution, thought.

You can use **ffmpeg** (which is multimedia framework available for linux, windows and macOS) and delegate generating a video thumbnail to it by running a new process. I don't know where do you want to use this, because it could not be very efficient.

```
var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg")
{
    Arguments = $"-i {pathMovie} -ss 00:00:01 -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -s 550x450 -aspect 5:3 {pathThumbnail} -y",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = false
};

var proc = new Process { StartInfo = procStartInfo };
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have to use in AWS lamda to generate thumbnails from S3 bucket with the Linux machine. Does the above code work in that case?

Comment: Yes, it could work, but like i said - it could not be very efficient. The code above is just example how to run a new process and it makes no difference whether you run it on linux, os x or windows.